# Vector Iterators (of String) inside a Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, vector, iterator

I am trying to create a C++ Map which contains a String as the Key and a C++ Iterator(a Vector Iterator) as the Value.
In the Attached Code: I have a Vector called **numbers** which keeps the key's value and I am taking the iterator of this vector element storing it in the map called **Directory**.
The code should work as written but when I try to print the Directory Key-Value, some of the Values are not appearing in the Directory. I really need a second look at this as I have now spent hours and don't know where I am wrong. Please Help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
vector<string> keys;
map<string, vector<string>::iterator> Directory;
void printStuff()
{
    for (auto x : Directory)
    {
        cout << "Key: " << x.first << "---- Value: " << (*x.second) << endl;
    }
}
void add()
{
    string name;
    string number;
    printf("Enter Key : ");
    cin >> name;
    printf("Enter Value : ");
    cin >> number;
    keys.push_back(number);
    vector<string>::iterator num;
    num = keys.end() - 1;
    Directory[name] = num;
}
int main()
{
    int ch = 10;
    while (ch != 0)
    {
        cout << "1. Add a Contact\n";
        cout << "2. Lookup Directory\n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            add();
            break;

        case 2:
            printStuff();
            break;

        case 3:
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems *very* brittle in the face of vector modifications invalidating iterators. I suggest you re-think your design.

Answer (score 0):

After this statement

```
keys.push_back(number);
```

all early appended to the map iterators of the vector can be invalid because the vector can reallocate memory for its elements. So the program has undefined behavior.

Instead of the vector use the container `std::list`.

Comment: @DaveCopperfield You can use the same iterators.